# Docker-machine how to chose IP with virtualbox driver

Tags: docker, virtualbox, system-administration, docker-machine

I need to create a machine with specific Ip. I tried somethig like this :

`docker-machine create test --url tcp://192.168.59.103:2376 -d "virtualbox"`

Is there any way to do that ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is still not possible, there is an open [feature request](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1709) to make it. The only way you can somehow specify it, is to provide `--virtualbox-hostonly-cidr` property, while you run `create` command for docker-machine, like:

```
--virtualbox-hostonly-cidr "192.168.99.1/24"
```

Which make you dcoker machine ip within a range of CIDR 192.168.99.1/24. Note, it'll not work, if you'll try to specify CIDR like `/32` to recieve only one available ip address.